# Adding, updating and erasing elements from nested json

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently working on a diagram / tree graph generator, to achieve this I'm using two libraries: [**GraphView**](https://github.com/oss-bandb/GraphView) to generate the graph and [**ZoomLayout**](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout) to move around the view. The main idea of this project is to save all JSON's within an AWS database and then load a list of all the created graphs.

Since the GraphView library doesn't have capability to change or add data from the nodes I decided to create a JSON parser in order to notify new changes and redraw the shape of the graph. So far I managed to create a JSON parser that can read the following format.

**example.json**

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "B",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "G",
                    "children": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "D",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "E",
                            "children": [
                                {}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "F",
                            "children": [
                                {}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The parser uses a class to iterate over all the nodes within the JSON string named **Nodes**.

**Nodes.kt**

```
class Nodes(
    var name: String,
    val children: MutableList<Nodes>
){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "\nName:$name\nChildren:[$children]"
    }

    fun hasChildren(): Boolean {
        return !children.isNullOrEmpty()
    }
}
```

With that JSON, the app generates the following graph:
[image: Generated Graph]

### **The problem**

Within this section you can enter a new string which will replace the current one in the selected node. This is done by editing the string without any mapping, using the String.replace() method. But this method doesn't allow me to erase or add new nodes to the current JSON string.

[image: Editing Node]

To map the JSON properly I decided to make use of GSON and a MutableList. First I set up the MutableList with the data from the current JSON and then I add a new node in front of the clicked node. The issue is that when I try to print the MutableList as a string the app throws an stackoverflow. This also happens if I try to map it to JSON format using GSON.

This the code that I use to replace the JSON.

```
// Method used to replace the current JSON with a new one by replacing the selected node with new data
    private fun replaceJson(oldData: String, newData: String): Graph {
        newGraph = Graph()
        newStack.clear()
        mNodesList.clear()

        val gson = Gson()
        var mappedNodes: Nodes = gson.fromJson(json, Nodes::class.java)

        val mapper = ObjectMapper()

        newStack.push(mappedNodes)
        while (newStack.isNotEmpty()) {
            replaceData(newStack.pop(), oldData, newData)
        }

        var position = -1
        for(element in mNodesList){
            if(element.name == currentNode!!.data.toString()){
                println("Adding new node to ${mNodesList.indexOf(element)}")
                position = mNodesList.indexOf(element)
            }
        }

        mNodesList.add(position + 1, Nodes(newData, mNodesList))


        for(node in mNodesList){
            println(node.name)
        }

        //Stackoverflow
//        println(mNodesList.toString())

        //Stackoverflow
//        val newJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mNodesList)
//        println("json::: \n $newJson")

        json = json.replace(oldData, newData, ignoreCase = false) //WIP Not final
        return newGraph
    }

    // This method replaces some node data with the newly entered data
    // this method uses recursivity to load all children and names in order
    private fun replaceData(nodes: Nodes, oldData: String, newData: String) {
        for (node in nodes.children) {
            if (node.hasChildren()) {
                if (node.name == oldData) {
                    mNodesList.add(node)
                    newGraph.addEdge(Node(nodes.name), Node(newData)) //<--- replaces data
                    newStack.push(Nodes(newData, node.children))
                } else {
                    mNodesList.add(node)
                    newGraph.addEdge(Node(nodes.name), Node(node.name))
                    newStack.push(node)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I read some posts where people uses HashMaps but I'm quite lost and I don't think I understand how JSON mapping works.

### **Summary**

I'm looking for a way to add and delete nodes from the string (JSON) provided above, but I don't quite know how to fix what I already have. It's the first time I'm working with JSON and Lists with Kotlin so I would greatly apreciate any information or help, any insights on how to improve or workaround will also be apreciated.

If anyone wants to see the code it's currently public in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/asanme/tree-diagram-maker).

PD: I tried providing as much information as possible, if the question is still unclear I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is in a similar situation, here's the solution I came up with.
I ended up simplifying the JSON structure I was using since having a nested JSON was giving me so many problems. I decided to link children and parents in another way. This is the current JSON structure:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "data": "A",
            "parent": "root"
        },
        {
            "data": "B",
            "parent": "A"
        },
        {
            "data": "C",
            "parent": "A"
        },
        {
            "data": "G",
            "parent": "B"
        },
        {
            "data": "D",
            "parent": "C"
        },
        {
            "data": "E",
            "parent": "D"
        },
        {
            "data": "F",
            "parent": "D"
        },
        {
            "data": "H",
            "parent": "F"
        },
        {
            "data": "I",
            "parent": "H"
        },
        {
            "data": "J",
            "parent": "I"
        },
        {
            "data": "K",
            "parent": "J"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also remade my Nodes class, and separated it two parts: **Nodes.kt** and **SingleNode.kt**.
Now the Nodes class only contains a list of SingleNode, and SingleNode contains the data of the node and its parent.

```
/**
 * This class represets all the nodes
 * @param nodes represents a list of all the existing nodes
 */
class Nodes(var nodes: List<SingleNode>)
```

```
/**
 * This class represents the instance of a single node
 * @param data name of the node
 * @param name of its parent or upper node
 */
class SingleNode(var data: String, var parent: String)
```

Once I had those classes, I used the GSON library to map the JSON string into a Nodes object.

```
val tree: Nodes = gson.fromJson(json, Nodes::class.java)
```

With this structure I was able to map the nodes into a `LinkedHashMap`, which I can then use to add, remove or edit any key and value (which represent the name of the node and the parent).
By using a `mutableListOf<SingleNode>` and `GSON` I can then recreate a JSON based on the previously modified HashMap.